# How to add link on SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, hyperlink, xlink

Why do the links in the SVG file stop working if an img tag is used (HTML, svg, development)?
How can I add link SVGs that are included in a  tag? [puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SO4R.png)

In this puzzle when I move my mouse around on top of the puzzle piece it stutters back-and-forth.

link don't work properly.

Comment: Maybe add some code? It would make the question more clear.

Comment: Please read about the [SVG's <a> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a)

Answer (score 2):

For example

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg></a>
```

Comment: I think you can work off this.